# Changing tab on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this code for implementing tab for the website

```
 <span style=" float: left; width: 131px; padding: 8px 0px 8px 0px;color: #fff; font-size: 20px;background: none; text-align: left; margin: 0% 0% 0% 9%;" > 6 more steps :</span>
                <input type="radio" name="sky-tabs" checked="" id="sky-tab1" class="sky-tab-content-1">
                <label for="sky-tab1"><span><span> <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Travel Data
</span></span></label>

                <input type="radio" name="sky-tabs" id="sky-tab2" class="sky-tab-content-2">
                <label for="sky-tab2"><span><span> <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Hotels
</span></span></label>

                <input type="radio" name="sky-tabs" id="sky-tab3" class="sky-tab-content-3">
                <label for="sky-tab3"><span><span> <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Activities
</span></span></label>

                <input type="radio" name="sky-tabs" id="sky-tab4" class="sky-tab-content-4">
                <label for="sky-tab4"><span><span> <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Transfers
</span></span></label>
                <input type="radio" name="sky-tabs" id="sky-tab5" class="sky-tab-content-5">
                <label for="sky-tab5"><span><span> <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Summary
</span></span></label>
                <input type="radio" name="sky-tabs" id="sky-tab6" class="sky-tab-content-6">
                <label for="sky-tab6"><span><span> Payment
</span></span></label>
```

Then I have required information for each tab in rest of the section. And I have buttons like this inside each tab --

```
                  <div class="total_price_list_ft">
                    <a href="#">Proceed to Activities <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
                  </div>
                   <div class="total_price_list_ft_rt">
                    <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left"></i> Back to Travel Data</a>
                  </div>
```

How Can i implement tab change function here on button click ?

Please guide.

Comment: You're missing a crucial component here: JavaScript. There are a million tabbing tutorials for JS on the web; did you see any?

Comment: Yes, But in most of the tutorial they just used next and back button, for my case every tab has its own button with the text of the next tab name

Comment: As I say, you need JS. Not sure why the tutorial you found didn't mention this, if you're sure it didn't. Buttons in HTML don't do anything for tabs until you hook some JS into them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `onclick` event

```
href="javascript:void(0)" onclick = "$('#sky-tab2').click();
```

where sky-tab1,2,3, .. is the id.

Answer (score 1):

You can user jquery tabs check following url

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: I did check this,
can not use this as it spoils the whole styling of the page

Answer (score 0):

You can add [Tabs from JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) or even considering using Bootstrap!

Bootstrap has support for tabs too. [Bootstrap Javacript](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/)

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the JQuery Function

```
  $('input[name=sky-tabs]).click(function{
   #Write the code specfic to the tab here
    });
```